# How to correctly escape quotes in JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json

I use `JSON.stringify` and get the following result

```
{
  "key1": "1",
  "key2": "2",
  "key3": [
    {
      "jobCode": "full",
      "income": "1",
      "desc": "test"
    },
    {
      "jobCode": "xxx",
      "income": "2",
      "desc": "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need to get the following result

```
{
      "key1": "1",
      "key2": "2",
      "key3": [
        {
          \"jobCode\": \"full\",
          \"income\": \"1\",
          \"desc\": \"test\"
        },
        {
          \"jobCode\": \"xxx\",
          \"income\": \"2\",
          \"desc\": \"test\"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to make sure that value for key3 gets in quotes. and internal value quotes get escaped

I tried `JSON.strigify` but it gives me the first result but i need the second

Comment: Your desired result is invalid JSON though - it couldn't be `JSON.parse`d correctly, this sounds like a very odd thing to want to do

Comment: the reason i need it because spring boot java bean accepts the second one

Comment: spring boot accepts a `String` and then it does the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use **JSON.stringify** on **key3**, then replace it into the object, it will be passed as a string.

```
var obj = {"key1":"1","key2":"2","key3":[{"jobCode":"full","income":"1","desc":"test"},{"jobCode":"xxx","income":"2","desc":"test"}]};

var jsonKey3 = JSON.stringify(obj.key3);

obj.key3 = jsonKey3;

console.log(obj);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```